# how set backcolor to the original color of the custom textbox

Tags: c#, custom-controls

I'm trying to change the forecolor for the textbox on focus (custom control)

```
 protected override void OnEnter(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnEnter(e);
            BackColor = this.Parent.BackColor;
            ForeColor = _OnFocusForeColor;
        }
```

but how to back to the original color of the forecolor?

I tried:

```
protected override void OnLeave(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLeave(e);
            BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
            ForeColor = this.ForeColor;
}
```

but doesn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of ideas:

**First option**

Set a break point on the line where you change the color, and debug your solution. When it stops at that line, hover over the existing `ForeColor` to see what the value is called before it is changed. Now you can use that color when you set it back.

**Second option**

Before setting the new color, save the already existing value in a property which you can then access and reapply later:

```
protected override void OnEnter(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnEnter(e);
    BackColor = this.Parent.BackColor;
    
    // New:
    PreviousColor = ForeColor;
    ForeColor = _OnFocusForeColor;
}
```

..and then later, obviously:

```
    ForeColor = PreviousColor;
```

Comment: thank you so much, the Second option is what I want